# Proving a walk contains a trail

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove the following theorem that (I think) defines a trail:

> Let $G$ be a graph that has a walk between vertices $v$ and $w$. Then $G$ has a walk between vertices $v$ and $w$ that does not use repeated edges.

Intuitively, if I consider a walk with repeated edges between vertices {$v_0, v_1,...,v_n$}, then in order to get from $v_0$ to $v_n$ any repeated edges must occur an odd number of times otherwise you won't reach the end of the walk. The repeated paths are ultimately redundant.

As far as a formal proof goes, I'm thinking that induction is the way to go, but I'm not sure. I'm also thinking that I need to prove that the points on a graph are transitive, but that might be a bit off base.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Strong induction will work, but it is useful to reframe the problem slightly: "In a graph $G$, then any two vertices which are endpoints of a walk are also endpoints of a trail." This way, you aren't forced to only consider walks with the particular endpoints $v$ and $w$, and the inductive argument has fewer technical restrictions (probably conceptually simpler, too).

Comment: I think induction on the length of the walk is enough. The base case is trivial. To from $n$ to $n+1$, remove the last edge $e_{n+1}$ apply your induction hypothesis and distinguish 2 cases whether $e_{n+1}$ appear in the obtained path (in which case a prefix is enough to connect v and w) or not in which case you can add it to your path.

Comment: It is not true that you have to pass each edge an odd number of times. Just think of an otherwise simple path, where at one point (actually, to nodes and the connecting edge) you "attach" a cycle.

Comment: @lepdeffard Is there anything wrong with my answer? If you are satisfied, please accept it. If not, comment on what you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructive way for proving your theorem: Assume that you are given a walk from $s$ to $e$ that uses an edge $e=(a,b)$ twice. Then you also pass its nodes $a$ and $b$ twice. This means that the walk contains a closed subwalk, which you can remove, but still having a walk from $s$ to $e$.

Now assume the total multiplicity of edges is N. By the operation described above, you lower this number by at least one. So you find a simple walk after finitely many steps.